# Http to Https redirect breaks website when enabled

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, rewrite, azure

I have an Azure VM with IIS8 and the URL rewrite module installed.
I have a single website configured, with both default http (80) and https (443) bindings (for all unassigned traffic).

Both http and https work fine and load the website, however, when I apply some kind of HTTP to HTTPS redirect both http://mydomain and https://mydomain stop working.

I have tried using the standard HTTP Redirect module and I've tried to create a rule using URL Rewrite using the following: 
http://www.meltedbutter.net/wp/?p=231

Thanks for any ideas:)

Comment: Does HTTPS work when you don't have the rewrite/redirect in place?

Comment: yes, both endpoints work as long as I dont have any redirect enabled. I can have the rule enabled in Url Rewrite, site doesn't work...press disable rule and site works again. Same goes for HTTP Redirect module.

Comment: Is there anything logged by the web server? It sounds like it might be a redirect loop, does any error show up in the browser?

Comment: the browser just gives me a timeout. Don't find anything useful in the IIS logs unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what caused the issue, but at some point I could get the redirect to work on the subdomain, but the virtual dir/application still wouldn't redirect. 
Eventually decided to delete and recreate the virtual dir. and that 'fixed' the problem